# Skinned Window: Win32 API and DirectX

Tags: winapi, directx, gdi, alpha

I'm trying to create a borderless window using a WS_EX_LAYERED style window. The objective is to render graphics using DirectX directly to the desktop, using alpha to blend onto the current desktop windows.

Now on my system this technique seems to work perfectly. I can set various alpha levels and achieve different levels of transparency. Unfortunately several users have reported severe performance problems and low frame rate, making this technique unusable.

The code setup is as follows:

1. Create a layered (**WS_EX_LAYERED** extended-style) window.
2. Initialize DirectX using the window HWND.
3. Create a render target using the **CreateRenderTarget** DirectX method.

Then during the render loop:

1. Render graphics to the render target using DirectX calls.
2. Get the HDC handle to the DirectX render target surface using **GetDC** method.
3. Update the window contents using the **UpdateLayeredWindow** function, specifying the DirectX surface HDC.

My question is: Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to improve the performance of the window update. I have tried various things, like locking the render target and manually copying the bits to a DIB section to display in the window area, without success.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your window? Note MSDN's documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says "For best drawing performance by the layered window and any underlying windows, the layered window should be as small as possible."

You may be getting a performance boost if compositing (Aero) is enabled. If Windows is already compositing, it won't have to do as much extra work to draw layered windows.

If you're not seeing any difference in performance depending on compositing, then I am probably completely off base here.

Comment: I have Aero disabled by default, but I have also tried it enabled and there is no change in the performance for me.